# como devolver valor de un input en js

Tags: javascript

Tengo un input con un numero al modificarlo y no sea correcto me manda una alerta quiero me devuelva a numero principal me queda con el numero modificado como hago eso en js? gracias

Comment: mantener el numero anterior en otra variable y solo actualizarlo si pasa la prueba

Comment: como asi no te entiendo

Comment: Lo siento, Miguel... Es que tampoco me quedó clara tu pregunta. Qué es o que intentas hacer? Para ser más claro, puedes leer [cómo elaborar una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). También necesitaremos que realices un [ejemplo mínimo completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Mientras más clara sea tu pregunta, más fácil será para nosotros responderla. Lee los recursos que te presento y edita tu pregunta para incluir la información relevante. Saludos

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.